# itemview may not be null error in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add multiple views in a recyclerview. So first I added getItemView method,

```
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            return type.get(position);

    }
```

Then in the oncreateviewholder method I added this

```
        @Override
            public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = null;
                switch (viewType){

                    case 0:
                        v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.view1, parent, false);



                    case 1:
                        v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.view2, parent, false);;




                    case 2:
                        v = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext ()).inflate (R.layout.view3, parent, false);


    }

    return new ViewHolder(v);

}
```

But when run it it's giving me   `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: itemView may not be null` error...

Comment: what is your `type` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Either your `type` collection returns wrong types that do not fall into this `switch` or your error lies somewhere else.

This is a snippet from my adapter and it works perfectly fine.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layoutResId = (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) ? R.layout.item_header : R.layout.item_content;
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutResId, parent, false));
}
```

Try adding a default case to this switch and see if it parses the layout then.

EDIT: and please clarify what `types` is in your code and how you initialize it

Answer (score -1):

Adapter's `getItemViewType()` returns the `number` of view type. As you have 3 views(`view1, view2, view3`), you should return 3 from `getItemViewType()` method.

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 3;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You are talking about `getViewTypeCount`. The method `getItemViewType` must return the type of the layout that needs to be inflated based on the position of the current item. Ideally a switch case is placed and each case points to the layout type that need to be inflated.